# How to get rid of these "tip of the day"-style annoying popups?

Tags: office365

Our company has introduced Office 365 and I continue getting these "tip of the day" balloon popups which disturb me and which are annoying. How do I turn those off for all Office applications so that they never appear again? I don't want to learn more. I just need to get my work done.

[image: Powerpoint Tell your story with video]

[image: Powerpoint Save time by reusing slides]

I assume that I will see those in Word, Excel, OneNote, Publisher, Outlook, Access as well, so please, if possible I'd like a solution for all of them.

And BTW: this time-saving new feature (last screenshot) is slower than good old copy/paste.

Answer (score 2):

This post might have an answer:
[Office 365 Outlook balloon/tips?](https://www.reddit.com/r/Office365/comments/f5fonh/office_365_outlook_balloontips/)

A user there has set the following two registry items under the key
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\TeachingCallouts`:

- `SLRToggleReplaceTeachingCalloutID` : Value `2`
- `UseTighterSpacingTeachingCallout` : Value `2`

This solved that user's problem with popups.

Note that if this solves your own problem, but that this fix is undone
after reboot, then this setting is forced by your administrator.
You could in this case create a Startup script to set these
registry items when you login and before you start Office.

Comment: Those are already set to 2 on my machine, but there is `RibbonOverflowTeachingCalloutID` which is set to 1

Comment: There is a list of them [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/186354/outlook-remove-blue-tip-boxes). Value `2` may be "do not show again".